# Retrieve all the values in SharedPreference - Monoandroid

Tags: android, dictionary, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, key-value

How can we retrieve all the values in SharedPreferences - Monoandroid?

**Context:**  I have a SharedPreference named "ActivatedModuleList". Values inside ActivatedModuleList is as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="1006">Level6-PrimaryHolder Access</string>
<string name="1007">Level7-SecondaryKey Access</string>
</map>
```

More Key/Values will be added or may be removed from this "ActivatedModuleList". At some point, i need to read all the key-value Pairs from this SharedPreferences.

***Question:***

How can we retrieve all the values in SharedPreferences through Monoandroid?

**or** 
Got this java code from Net, What is Monodroid equivalent of

```
Map<String, ?> prefsMap = sharedPreferences.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet())
{
   Log.v("SharedPreferences", entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With this you can iterate through all preferences:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> preference in prefs.All)
{
    Log.Verbose("SharedPreferences", String.Format("{0}:{1}", preference.Key, preference.Value));
}
```